# Can I upload complete folders to MediaFire with PHP?

Tags: php, sdk, mediafire

I've been looking at the SDKs available for MediaFire, but so far it seems they are all just for uploading single files.

Is there any way that I can upload entire folders with their files to my MediaFire account? Similar to using the MF desktop software.

The reason I'm asking is because I want to back up content from my external HDD to my MF account, but zipping it all and then uploading a zip file is not an option as I will need to be able to access individual files from it on MF when necessary.
I also cannot put all the data in the MF upload folder on my desktop because the data is about 1Tb in size and my laptop only has a 512Gb SSD.

Is there any way to upload all that data from another location than the MF uploads folder on my desktop?

Comment: Hey, what have you tried so far? We'd love to help you, but we don't write code for you

Comment: Well, I've downloaded the PHP SDK and had a look at the code and what it can do.
I would actually pay someone to write the code for me to upload all the data from an external HDD, but I am just wondering if it "is possible" to do that with a PHP upload.
I thought that uploading data like that from folders would be a common thing that people do for creating cloud backups, but all the SDKs seem to only do single file uploads.

Comment: I haven't yet worked with the MediaFire API, but uploading multiple files is in essence the same as multiple single file uploads. But SO is not a place to hire freelance webdevs, so I'm flagging this as off-topic. You can mail me for more info and such.